# Fourier transform of an infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a Fourier series for a sequence $s_n$ ($n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\dots$), like $s_n=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}f_k e^{ikn}$? For example what would be $f_k$ for sequence $s_n=\frac{1}{n^2+1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g(x)=\frac {x^{2}} {1+x^{2}}$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ then the Fourier series of $g$ converges to $g$ at every  point. So $g(\frac 1 n)=\sum \hat {g} (k) e^{ikn}$ This gives the expansion you want. The idea is to define a nice periodic function $g$ with $g(\frac 1 n)=s_n$.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice point!